# JavaScript: Init Array from string

Tags: javascript

A beginners question: I am trying to create and init an Array of users using the following string as initial data in JavaScript:

```
{ "user": {"notes": [{ "text": "Hello ", "date": "12\/1\/2013 5:01:36 AM", }], "name": "Alex"} }, { "user": { "notes": [{ "text": "Hi ", "date": "12\/1\/2013 5:15:19 PM"}, { "text": "It is me",  "date": "12\/1\/2013 6:23:54 PM"}], "name": "Anna"} }
```

Is it possible in general (how?) or am I completely getting it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. It contains a syntax error (possible a typo in the question) - an invalid comma after the first user's `date`, and it is also a list of objects that are not enclosed with the array syntax `[]`.

The corrected json and example of parsing is:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RDVZm/)**

```
var json = '[{ "user": {"notes": [{ "text": "Hello ", "date": "12\/1\/2013 5:01:36 AM" }], "name": "Alex"} }, { "user": { "notes": [{ "text": "Hi ", "date": "12\/1\/2013 5:15:19 PM"}, { "text": "It is me",  "date": "12\/1\/2013 6:23:54 PM"}], "name": "Anna"} }]';
//          ^ the list of objects need to be enclosed with []
var users = JSON.parse(json);

for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++)
{
  console.log(users[i].user.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the JSON code is valid, use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) for that. There is an error in your code, I fixed it in the code below.
2. Use **[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** to transfer it to an object.
3. To be compatible to all browsers make sure you have [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) included as well (not all browsers have the JSON object to call the JSON.parse function).
4. As mentioned by Anthony the result is not an array but an object. To iterate over the user list see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/6uECV/) or the example below.

**EXAMPLE**

```
var str = "[{user:...";
var userList = JSON.parse(str);

for(var i in userList){
    var user = userList[i].user;
    document.write(user.name + "<br/>");
}
```

**CORRECTED JSON**

```
[
{
    \"user\": {
        \"notes\": [
            {
                \"text\": \"Hello \",
                \"date\": \"12/1/2013 5:01:36 AM\"
            }
        ],
        \"name\": \"Alex\"
    }
},
{
    \"user\": {
        \"notes\": [
            {
                \"text\": \"Hi \",
                \"date\": \"12/1/2013 5:15:19 PM\"
            },
            {
                \"text\": \"It is me\",
                \"date\": \"12/1/2013 6:23:54 PM\"
            }
        ],
        \"name\": \"Anna\"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Worth noting that `user` in the provided JSON is **not** an array, it's just an object.

Comment: Why is this downvoted twice? Whats wrong? There should be a rule that one can't downvote without a comment...

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you got that string using an ajax call, right?
and you can convert that string to an javascript object using JSON.parse(strToBeConverted)
in all modern browsers.
What if there is no such built-in JSON object? Do as below says,
1. import JS downloaded from [this site](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) which is created by Douglas Crockford,
2. use JSON.parse to do your business.